# Access Text in UIAlertTextField using Alert class in Model

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

I've created an Alert class in my model layer for presenting simple alerts, and this works great.

```
class Alert {
    class func showBasic(title: String, message: String, vc: UIViewController) {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
        alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil))
        vc.present(alert, animated: true)
    }
}
```

I'm trying to add a second alert type with a text field, and have the result of the textField available in the view controller. I've tried with a completion handler, but the completion handler fires when the alert is finished being presented, not when text is actually entered. How can I capture the text in the text field and use that in the view controller?

```
class func withInput(title: String, message: String, vc: UIViewController, placeholder: String, btnTitle: String, complete: (_ result:String) -> Void) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = placeholder
    }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: btnTitle, style: .default, handler: nil))
    vc.present(alert, animated: true)
    if let text = alert.textFields?[0].text {
        complete(text)
    }
}
```

Comment: To use it in a controller you should create it there and set a delegate to your view controller

Comment: I'd rather not create it in the controller to avoid unnecessary clutter. There has to be a way using delegation from the model to the controller, no?

Comment: you can make Alert as a delegate and then delegate it to the controller but it would be even more clutter?

Comment: and to make delegation work properly you have to keep reference to object so it is not released from memory

Comment: so either unnecessary clutter or unnecessary complication... I was afraid of that

Comment: https://oleb.net/2018/uialertcontroller-textfield/ this looks pretty good actually

Comment: It should work great for this example but it is still a lot of code to be added

Comment: The solution to my problem is actually pretty simple - I was ignoring the addAction completion handler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The completion handler needs to go in the addAction's completion handler

```
class func withInput(title: String, message: String, vc: UIViewController, placeholder: String, btnTitle: String, complete: @escaping (_ result:String) -> Void) {
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: title, message: message, preferredStyle: .alert)
    alert.addTextField { (textField) in
        textField.placeholder = placeholder
    }
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: btnTitle, style: .default, handler: { [weak alert] (_) in
        if let text = alert?.textFields?[0].text {
            complete(text)
        }
    }))
    vc.present(alert, animated: true)
}
```